# How to retrieve all _ids of updated documents in MongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to run multiple upsert queries using bulkWrite(). But the problem is, bulkWrite only returns inserted _ids not updated _ids. How can I get all 
_ids in this query?

```
var insertCommand = Builders<myObject>.Update.SetOnInsert(d => d.Name, object.Name).SetOnInsert(d => d.Age, object.Age);
var updateCommand = Builders<myObject>.Update.Set(d => d.LastRequest, object.DateTime);
var updateQueries = Builders<myObject>.Update.Combine(new[] { updateCommand, insertCommand });
var filter = Builders<myObject>.Filter;
var findQuery = filter.And(filter.Eq(e => e.Name, object.Name), filter.Eq(e => e.City, object.City));
var upsertObject = new UpdateOneModel<myObject>(findQuery, updateQueries) { IsUpsert = true };
bulkOps.Add(upsertObject);
var result = await Collection.BulkWriteAsync(bulkOps);
```

Comment: Did you get Ids of modified documents from bulkWrite response?

Answer (score 0):

Using `BulkWriteAsync`, I don't think this can be done. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#definition) on the MongoDB `bulkWrite` operation states the following:

> Returns:
>
> A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with
>   write concern or false if write concern was disabled.
>
> A count for each write operation.
>
> An array containing an _id for each successfully
>   inserted or upserted documents.

What works, however, for a single instance is this:

```
var result = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(findQuery, updateQueries, new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<myObject> { IsUpsert = true, ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After});
```

After running this, `result` will hold the modified document including its `_id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew I can use `FindOneAndUpdate` but I can not use it as bulk operation. I need to do something bulk.

Comment: I'm afraid you're left with only one choice in this case where you'd need to retrieve all the `_id`s upfront that would be matched by your find condition and then do what you've been doing.